# Change AD password using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to access my ad server(for entry/User modification) remotely, I got connection using port 389 with my public IP but it doesn't let me to make modification in entry(able to retrieve entry). So, I try to make connection using port 636 but I am not able to connect using this port. 
So, can you please let me know what changes do I need to make to connect on 636 or How can I modify Entry(i.e change password(unicodepwd)) on port 389?

Thanks in Advance.!

Comment: Also guide me for where/how to find related certificate files from AD?

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming stack exchange you should have better audience with this kind of question in ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

Using PHP, you can change an AD user password using LDAP with a simple bind on an SSL connexion.

For this you need to install a certificate on you AD server. The simple way (not the more attractive) is to install Microsoft Certificate Server on your domain (Enterprise installation see [Configuring Microsoft Active Directory for SSL Access](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Configuring_Microsoft_Active_Directory_for_SSL_Access)) and then to reboot your domain controler. You can also generate a certificate with OpenSSL and install it on the computer (see [How to enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051/en-us)).

Here is a sample of an LDIF File that allow to create a user with his password on an SSL connexion, you will find the way I generate the base 64 string for the password :

```
# Imported with :
# ldifde -i -t 636 -f .\Annuaire3.ldf
# Password generated by ("" must be encoded inside):
# stringconverter.exe \"test.2011\" /unicode /encode
# Connexion then tested with :
# runas /user:jdupont cmd.exe (password is test.2011)

dn: cn=Jean Dupont,OU=MonOU,DC=societe0,DC=fr
changetype: add
objectClass: user
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: Jean Dupont
givenName: Jean
sn: Dupont
mail: jean.Dupont@societe.fr
telephoneNumber: 9999
userAccountControl: 544
sAMaccountName: jdupont
userPrincipalName: jdupont@societe.fr
unicodePwd:: IgB0AGUAcwB0AC4AMgAwADEAMQAiAA==
```