# Add password user using LDAP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, active-directory, ldap

I searched every days for my problem, I tried many solutions and I didn't find... :(

I want to create an user using ldap_add with PHP. Working fine without enable account and without password. You find the code below.

Can you help me, please?

**Config** : 
PHP 5.6 
Windows Server 2012 R2 with AD

I can enable an account when I use `$info["useraccountcontrol"]=544;` but the account isn't with a password... User must loggon without password and type his new password at the first connection. *

I tried to add a password with `$info['userPassword']`  and chand useraccountontrol at 512 and I get this error :

***ldap_add(): Add: Server is unwilling to perform***

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name_build"]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST["lastname_build"]);
$department = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST["department_build"]));
$title = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST["title_build"]));
$dn="CN=$name OU=Users, o=Domocom, c=net";

$ds = ldap_connect("192.168.1.1",389);  
if ($ds) {

    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); // IMPORTANT
    ldap_bind($ds, "administrateur@domocom.net", "password");

    // Prépareles données
    $cn = $info["cn"] = "$lastname $name";
    $info["sn"]="$name";
    $info["givenname"]="$lastname";
    $info["displayname"]="$lastname $name";
    $info["name"]="$lastname $name";
    $info["userprincipalname"]= "$lastname.$name@domocom.net";
    $info["samaccountname"]= "$lastname.$name";
    $info["title"]="$title";
    $info["department"]="$department";
    $info["mail"]="$lastname.$name@domocom.fr";
    $info["postalcode"]="69009";
    $info["objectClass"][0]="user";
    //$info['userPassword'] = "password";
    //$info["useraccountcontrol"]=544;

    $r = ldap_add($ds,"CN=$cn,OU=Users,OU=Direction,OU=Domocom-SP,DC=domocom,DC=net", $info);
    ldap_close($ds);
} else {
    echo "unable to connect to ldap server";
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot.

PS : it's fake society for my school. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an AD you might need to use a secure LDAP-Connection.

For that you'll need to call `ldap_connect('ldaps://192.168.1.1:<port of the AD>');`. Calling `ldap_connect` with two parameters is deprecated and should be avoided. Use it with an LDAP-URI!

You can also omit the `if…else` around the `ldap_connect` as it will return true in almost all cases. And a `true` return-value does not mean that a connection to the server actually as established. A connection is first established on the first ldap_-command that needs a connection which is typically `ldap_bind`.

And then you might want to have a look at [Change AD password using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723038/change-ad-password-using-php), [Issue updating AD password using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29115533/issue-updating-ad-password-using-php) and [Change AD Password using PHP/COM/ADSI/LDAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011625/change-ad-password-using-php-com-adsi-ldap)